# Assign a Struct Pointer to Double Pointer Struct

Tags: c

The problem: Create a struct with double pointer to be ale to sort the cards without changing the memory location of each card.

The cards are used in other parts of the program.

Diagram:

```
 *deck           .**card    .n_cards 
 +------+       +--------+----+
 |  x---|------>|  x     | 3  |
 +------+       +--------+----+
                   |              +-----+
                   +------------->|  x  |
                                  +-----+
                  .value .suit       |
                    +----+---+       |
                    |    |   |<------+
                    +----+---+
                    |    |   |
                    +----+---+
                    |    |   |
                    +----+---+
```

Code:

```
struct card_tag {
  unsigned value;
  suit_t suit;
};typedef struct card_tag card_t;

struct deck_tag {
  card_t ** cards;
  size_t n_cards;
};
typedef struct deck_tag deck_t;

void add_card_to(deck_t * deck, card_t c){
  deck->n_cards++;
  deck->cards = realloc(deck->cards, (deck->n_cards)*sizeof(*deck->cards));
  card_t * new_c = malloc(sizeof(*new_c));
  *new_c = c;
  deck->cards[deck->n_cards-1] = new_c;
  return;
}
```

The code is compiling without errors, but the sort changes the memory address of the cards.

The way I am using to link the **cards to the struct card is the correct way of doing this?

To sort the cards I'm using qsort.

```
qsort(hand2->cards, hand2->n_cards, sizeof(card_t), card_ptr_comp);
```

Comment: the usual way is `typedef struct foo_tag { /* ... */ } foo_t;` (disclaimer: yes, `..._t` can conflict with identifiers in POSIX.)

Comment: @Swordfish: There's nothing wrong with separate struct definition and typedef.

Comment: @MOehm I didn't say that it's wrong. It's just another source of redundancy and typoes.

Comment: That's subjective and not at all related to the OP's problem.

Comment: @MOehm I respect your opinion.

Comment: You store copies of the cards in your array. I think the idea is not to make copies, but to store pointers to cards that already exist elsewhere, perhaps an array that holds an unshuffled deck of cards. So you should probably pass `card_t *c` and then just assign `new_c = c`. (This technique of indirect sorting is especially useful when your objects are big or when you want to keep the array sorted with more than one criterion.)

Comment: @MOehm Yes, that is right. Just need to store pointers to pointers. "new_c = c" Doesn't compile. Incompatible types. struct to struct pointer.

Comment: In that case, you should also pass a pointer to a card (`card_t *c)` to the function. Unfortunately, you don't show the code where cou call `add_card_to`.

Comment: @MOehn The function create a card_t (malloc) and update the value with card_t passed in the function. Maybe I should do something like this "deck->cards[deck->n_cards-1] = &new_c;". But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to sort `hand2->cards`, which is of type `card_t **`, then you need to pass `sizeof(card_t*)` to `qsort`, and make sure your comparison function accepts `card_t **` as inputs.

I.e.

```
qsort(hand2->cards, hand2->n_cards, sizeof *hand2->cards, card_ptr_comp);
```

and

```
int card_ptr_comp(const void * a, const  void * b)
{
    const card_t* card_a = *(const card_t**)a;
    const card_t* card_b = *(const card_t**)b;

    return card_a->suit - card_b->suit;
}
```

(Update)

Perhaps this diagram can clarify what you have allocated, after calling `add_card_to` three times. You will have `deck->cards` point to a chunk in memory containing three pointers, and each of the pointers will point to a separately allocated card.

The `qsort` call is currently reordering the array of pointers, i.e. **swapping the order of pointers inside the array pointed by `deck->cards`**. It also works by accident, because `sizeof(card_t)` is equal to `sizeof(card_t*)` on your 64-bit machine.

```
                 card_t**
 *deck           .cards  .n_cards 
 +------+       +--------+----+
 |  x---|------>|  x     | 3  |
 +------+       +--------+----+   YOU ARE REORDERING THIS:
                   |              card_t* card_t* card_t*
                   |              +-----+-----+-----+
                   +------------->|  x  |  y  |  z  |
                                  +-----+-----+-----+
                  .value .suit       |     |     |
                    +----+---+       |     |     |
                    |    |   |<------+     |     |
                    +----+---+             |     |
                                           |     |
                  .value .suit             |     | 
                    +----+---+             |     |
                    |    |   |<------------+     |
                    +----+---+                   |
                                                 |
                  .value .suit                   | 
                    +----+---+                   |
                    |    |   |<------------------+
                    +----+---+
```

Your `add_card_to` function is also **copying** struct values to the heap-allocated space. This means that the cards added to the deck are not the same cards as in your main program.

If you are also allocating the cards outside this function, then you need to change the function to simply:

```
void add_card_to(deck_t * deck, card_t * c)
{
    deck->n_cards++;
    deck->cards = realloc(...);
    deck->cards[deck->n_cards - 1] = c;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cast `a` and `b` to `const card_t**` and not just `card_t**` ?

Comment: @luci88filter: it's just a preference to keep pointers to const if possible, if I am not going to change them. It "documents" the readonly nature of the variable, and you get a [compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/vzFa0h) if the pointed value gets changed accidentally.

Comment: @Groo The sort works. The problem is that it is changing the address of the cards.

Comment: @Ilidam: well, the sort only seems like it's working, because `sizeof(card_t*)` is accidentally equal to `sizeof(card_t)` on your machine, so pointers are luckily swapped without screwing everything up. Add an additional field to `card_t` to test my theory. If you have an array of pointers, `qsort` will reorder this array of pointers. This is what `qsort` does. Actual cards will **not** be moved in memory. If you have an additional set of allocated cards outside `add_card_to`, and you are `malloc`ing again, that's another issue. Impossible to tell without your actual, complete code (a [mcve]).